# Primeface confirmDialog accesibility

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, accessibility, confirm-dialog

The confirmation dialogues  are not accessible to my screenreader (Orca 3.22.2).

The reader only reads the header but not the message of the dialog. Since the focus is set on the first button by default (which is after the text most of the time) it is especially bothersome.

Did anyone ever managed to bypass this issue with using arias in the content or anything that might work?

Edit: The rendered code for the dialog:

```
 <div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="form:j_idt152_title" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite">
        <div>
           <span>Dialog Title </span>
           <a href="#" aria-label="Close" role="button">
                 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>       
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
           <span ></span>
           <span >Message that needs to be read</span>
        </div>

        </div>
           <input id="form:ok" name="form:ok" value="ok" title="explanation on button" type="submit">
         <input  value="close" type="button">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I assume its just something ARIA missing on the text of the confirm dialog. Can you inspect the HTML source of what is generated for the Confirm Dialog then we just need to figure out what ARIA role to put on the message.  If you figure out what needs to be done simple report it on the GitHub issues page of PraimeFaces

Comment: You' re right. I added the generated code for info (minus all the classes and style things) and the message doesn't have any role/aria. I'll lookup how these things work to see if I can offer a solution to fix the component.

Comment: And _**ALWAYS**_ include the relevant version info. The PF one in this case

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Issue created: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4043

Pull Request updating to latest ARIA standards will hopefully be accepted for PrimeFaces 6.3: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/4044